# save data into a remote database from my android app

Tags: android, database

Im starting in this android development world, I would like to create an app with a simple form that allows me to register information but not in a device database but in a remote database instead, so all my employees from their locations can register information in a central database that we in office can review or even them from their mobile phones. 
Im coming back from 10 yeards of not touching this development topics but at least i already did some simple apps , i have the idea of how they works, layouts, activitys , connections between them via references but remote db is not easy to find as the other basic lessons.

Links or info are more enough , thank you!

Comment: Be aware of: [JDBC vs Web Service for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15853367/295004) and reminder that asking for tutorials or off-site links is considered [off-topic for StackOverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261845/295004).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would create your database and set it up so that a 'web app' (web service) could connect to it.  The web service (which you write) can be as fancy as you want, or just provide basic CRUD (create, read, update, delete) functionality.  When published on an internet available domain, the API will be exposed to your app, which can call it with basic HTTPS requests (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE if your API is 'RESTful'). Search for WEBAPI 2.0 with Entity Framework Tutorials and you will find great examples.